# Регулярное выражение не работает с русскими символами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток! Почему это выражение -

```
preg_match_all('/\S{2,}/s', $text, $out);
```

Корректно работает с английскими символами и некорректно с русскими(срабатывает на одну букву)?

Comment: Скорее всего, потому что $text в юникоде. Добавьте модификатор `u`.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, потому что `$text` в юникоде. Добавьте модификатор `u`:

```
preg_match_all('/\S{2,}/us', $text, $out);
```

---

<sub>Ответ перенесен из комментария</sub>